# CodeIgniter sql query with limit and offset not showing results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to retrieve a list of names from the database after a search and due to the nature of the search, I have to use a custom sql and not the default codeigniter one. 
As I need to do pagination, I have to use a dynamic limit and offset. However, I found that it doesn't give me the proper results. I have tested this query in mysql and it works. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Please help

My Model:

```
public function count_search($id,$input){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE '%$input%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $count = $query->num_rows();
        if($count>0){
            return $count;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

public function search($limit,$start,$id,$input){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE '%$input%'";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            if($query->num_rows()>0){
                foreach($query->result()as $row){
                    $contacts[] = $row;
                }
                return $contacts;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. You forgot to mention limit parameters in your query

```
public function search($limit,$start,$id,$input){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', 
        first_name, last_name) LIKE '%$input%' Limit ".$start.",".$limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            foreach($query->result()as $row){
                $contacts[] = $row;
            }
            return $contacts;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: use the same in count_search

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I have tried that but i get this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%grac% LIMIT 0,1' at line 1

SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE '%grac% LIMIT 0,1

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing same issue in my recent project and it makes me crazy just by debugging the same thing and spent too many days on same issue.I've read one answer from this link : [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813397/codeigniter-database-query-bug-does-not-return-expected-results)
I've checked my $input value and i've seen that it comes with Circular brackets-->() in $input string value because of that LIKE operator not returning result in codeignitor and same query works in phpmyadmin fluently.

But when i removed circular brackets from string it's working fluently in codeignitor also. You need to check $input string not contains much special characters.